# PHP use regex to return substring

Tags: php, regex

I want to retrieve a substring out of a other string.

The beginning of the string has 2 possibilities. Let's say 'abc' or 'def'
After this string there is a ' character and a random word. After the word there is a colon and then a sentence. And at least the string ends with a ' again.

So some possibilities are:

`abc 'randomword: my sentence'`
or
`def 'otherrandomword: my other sentence'`

What I want to do is with PHP retrieve the sentence in the string.
So for the samples above there should be `my sentence` and `my other sentence`.

I looked into the use of `preg_replace` and `preg_match` but I can't find a solution for this problem.

Could someone help me out with this. I hope that I made everything clear. If any questions please ask.

Comment: What patterns did you try with `preg_match`? It would also help if you provided a real-life example input with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("/((\babc\b)|(\bdef\b)) '[a-zA-Z]+: (.*?)'/", $your_string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[4]);
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. But when I use the following string `zxc 'random: my sentence'`. Then it returns `my sentence`. But it only has to find when `abc` or `def` is at the beginning of the string.